# Unable to parse API Response

Tags: python, json

I am trying to parse a response from this API, [here](https://github.com/rcbops/qtest-swagger-client/blob/master/docs/TestlogApi.md#get_test_logs_list) . However it says the response type is `TestLogListResource` . How do I parse this as `json`?

Code to get response

```
from __future__ import print_statement
import time
import swagger_client
from swagger_client.rest import ApiException
from pprint import pprint

# Configure API key authorization: Authorization
swagger_client.configuration.api_key['Authorization'] = 'YOUR_API_KEY'
# Uncomment below to setup prefix (e.g. Bearer) for API key, if needed
# swagger_client.configuration.api_key_prefix['Authorization'] = 'Bearer'

# create an instance of the API class
api_instance = swagger_client.TestlogApi()
project_id = 789 # int | ID of the project
test_run_id = 789 # int | ID of the Test Run
page_size = 100 # int | The result is paginated. By the default, the number of objects in each page is 100 if this is omitted. You can specify your custom number (up to 999) in this parameter (optional) (default to 100)
page = 1 # int | By default the first page is returned but you can specify any page number to retrieve objects (optional) (default to 1)

try: 
    # Gets all Test Logs of a Test Run
    api_response = api_instance.get_test_logs_list(project_id, test_run_id, page_size=page_size, page=page)
    pprint(api_response)
except ApiException as e:
    print("Exception when calling TestlogApi->get_test_logs_list: %s\n" % e)
```

Sample response.

```
{'items': [{'actual_exe_time': 0,
            'attachments': None,
            'build_number': None,
            'build_url': None,
            'defects': None,
            'exe_end_date': datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 31, 5, 15, 43, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 19800)),
            'exe_start_date': datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 29, 5, 5, 43, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 19800)),
            'id': 250378315,
            'links': [{'href': 'https://xxe.qtestnet.com/api/v3/projects/11xx93/test-runs/128439614/test-logs/250378315',
                       'rel': 'self'},
                      {'href': 'https://xxe.qtestnet.com/api/v3/projects/11xx93/test-cases/50735105?versionId=69533056&showParamIdentifier=false',
                       'rel': 'test-case'},
                      {'href': 'https://demoinstance.qtestnet.com/api/v3/projects/120893/test-logs/250378315/attachments',
                       'rel': 'attachments'}],
            'name': None,
            'note': 'Mark to Steve',
            'planned_exe_time': 0,
```

Comment: first show code. Next you could use `print()` to see what you really get in response because real JSON should be a `string` and it shoud use only base types like integer, float, list, dict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class `TestLogListResource` has a function [to_dict](https://github.com/rcbops/qtest-swagger-client/blob/28220aa95d878922ca4b35c325706932adabea4e/swagger_client/models/test_log_list_resource.py#L160), maybe you just need this function. If you realy need json format, you can then `json.dumps`.

Comment: I was reading throught the class in an IDE..I did't see it..Thanks a lot.